# Sum few rows with condition on basis of other column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe as

```
column1     column2
 abc          5
 def          4
 ghi          7
 jkl          6
 lmn          9
```

I am looking for the solution like

```
final1=abc+ghi+jkl=18 and final2=def+lmn=13
```

so the final output is like

```
final1 = 18 and final2 = 13
```

I am trying to do this using Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by condition and column name and then `sum`:

```
L1=['abc','ghi','jkl']
L2=['def','lmn']

final1 = df.loc[df['column1'].isin(L1), 'column2'].sum()
final2 = df.loc[df['column1'].isin(L2), 'column2'].sum()
print (final1)
18
print (final2)
13
```